# Laravel 7 not displaying the img

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have also used \  or
**/** but not effective.

**Blade**

`<img  src="{{ public_path('images\about.jpg') }}">`

**PATH**

```
-public

   -images
      
      -about.jpg
```

Using inspect element the link looks fine:

`<img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\acc\public\images\about.jpg">`

Comment: you need a URL not a file path

Comment: It should be `asset()` not `public_path()`, You need to change the code to this `<img src="{{ asset('images/about.jpg') }}">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asset() function is usually used to access the files in public directory of Laravel Application:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/about.jpg') }}" alt="some description here">
```

The public_path() function returns the absolute path for a file which doesn't apply in this case.